# Xcode 7 GM iOS Archiving Error: code sign mismatch

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, watchos-2

I'm currently working on iOS/WatchOS2 app. And I want to upload to iTunesConnect.
I created all provision files, selected them in project build settings. But, when I try to archive my project, Xcode 7GM says:

```
error: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's.

        Embedded Binary Signing Certificate:    - (Ad Hoc Code Signed)
        Parent App Signing Certificate:     iPhone Distribution: INTER***. (***)
```

All certificates are for iOS distribution

AND, at first, I though that Xcode 7 GM has a bug, as beta versions. But, when I tried to archive my project on other mac (also Xcode 7GM), it archived silently. No errors.

What's going on?

I reseted project settings, Xcode settings, deleted old Xcode7Beta, reinstalled Xcode7GM, created new project and added my sources, but no effect.

What should I do?
How to archive my app?
From where Xcode gets Ad Hoc?

Is it possible that Xcode 7 GM produces this error as it is not release version?

Comment: Doesn't the error message tell you what's wrong?  The embedded binary is signed with an ad hoc certificate instead of the distribution certificate.

Comment: I am using distribution certificate. If I transfer my current project without any changes to other mac, it archives. It seems error appears only on my machine. I don't know the reason.

Comment: And do both macs have the certificates installed?  Did you export your developer profile?

Comment: Both macs have certificates installed. But I didn't export my developer profile. I just signed in from xcode to my account.